# The loading Gif shows up only after finishing all the backgrounds tasks,Wxpython AnimationCtrl

Tags: wxpython

I just started using wxpython recently for a UI work. In my UI I have a notebook with 5 pages and when user click on a button on first frame a lot of backend Tasks will start which causes the screen to freeze for a couple of minutes. So I wanted a loading gif to be displayed when I click on that button.

I added animation to my main frame where I am creating my notebook and hide it and tried displaying it inside the thread function. It executes thread function on right time but the gif only gets displayed after all the background tasks are finished

Comment: Use `wx.GetApp().Yield()` to yield control momentarily to the main loop. Without any code it's difficult to be specific.

Comment: offload the tasks to another thread and have the main thread play the animation until the tasks are complete